# Can I toggle a class via the data attribute on a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link that is generated by this:

```
link_to(unfavorite_node_path(node), class: "card-favorite-count", method: :post, remote: true,  data: { toggle_text: node.cached_votes_total, toggle_href: favorite_node_path(node), toggle_class: "favorited" }) do
   # Some Code
end
```

Notice that `toggle_text` and `toggle_href` work. But for some reason, `toggle_class` doesn't work.

Is there a way for me to do what I want to do, i.e. on a successful AJAX call, toggle the class of my `a` tag (i.e. just add the class `favorited` or remove it) without using a bunch of JS and just using data attributes like this?

Comment: How do `data-toggle_text` and `data-toggle_href` work? Is this Rails out-of-the-box js or are you using another js library?

Comment: @eirikir This is Rails out of the box HTML5 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is out-of-the-box Rails stuff.  I think it's possible you have a gem installed, or some Javascript library in place.  A search for 'rails toggle_href' returns nothing.

My guess is someone built a helper script to manage a user clicking on a link, firing off a AJAX call to set a value, and then toggle the display to update the UI.  This script probably isn't expecting toggle_class, and would need to be modified to check for the toggle_class option and update the UI.

That being said, you could very easily add a JQuery snippet like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*[data-toggle_class]').click(function(evt) {
        var link = $(this);
        var toggleClass = link.data('toggle_class');
        link.toggleClass(toggleClass);
    }
}
```